# How to validate fields appended with id on cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have my form fields where I am appending an id within a for loop.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Shipment.current_city'.$sh, array('label' => 'City')); ?>
```

I would like to know how to validate such dynamic fields. Currently Cake is not recognizing my validation rules from my model due to the appended id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the solution of your issue here.

http://php-dev-zone.blogspot.com/2013/08/dynamic-fields-validation-in-cakephp.html